# InternalCompilerError: Stack too deep, try using fewer variables

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Etender{


    //--------------------------- admin  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    address payable private owner;
    constructor()public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }


    //------------------------------Tender------------------------------------------------------

    struct tender  {

        uint tenderId;
        string tenderName;
        string tenderSector;
        string tenderLocation;
        string open;
        string close;
        string tenderCategory;
        string prequalification;
        uint tenderValue;
        bool status;
    }
    uint tid ;
    mapping(uint =>tender) private tenders;


    //-------------------------------Bidder--------------------------------------------------


    struct bidder {
      uint organisationId;
      string organisationName;
      address add;
      string pan;
      string bidderType;
      string city;
      string state;
      uint postalCode;
      string companyCategory;
      string natureOfBusiness;
    }
    uint bid;

    mapping(uint =>bidder) private bidders;
    mapping(address =>bool) private isRegistered;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint =>bool) )private isBidded;
    mapping(address =>bool) private isVerified;
    mapping(address =>uint) private bidderId;

    // ------------------------------winner ---------------------------------------------------

    struct win {
        address winner;
        uint bidAmount;
        uint tenderId;
    }

    mapping(uint =>win) private winner;


    //------------------------All bidding details ---------------------------------------------------

    struct allBidding {
        address bidder;
        uint bidAmount;
        uint tenderId;
    }
    uint biddingCount;
    mapping(uint =>allBidding) private allBiddings;

    // ----------------------------- create tender function ------------------------------------

    function createTender(string memory _name , string memory _sector ,string memory _location , 
    string memory _open , string memory _close ,string memory _catagory ,string memory _prequalification,
    uint _value  ) public {

        tenders[tid].tenderId = tid;
        tenders[tid].tenderName = _name;
        tenders[tid].tenderSector = _sector;
        tenders[tid].tenderLocation = _location;
        tenders[tid].open = _open;
        tenders[tid].close = _close;
        tenders[tid].tenderCategory = _catagory;
        tenders[tid].prequalification = _prequalification ;
        tenders[tid].tenderValue = _value ;
        tenders[tid].status = true ;
        tid++;
    }


    //---------------------------------- create bidders ------------------------------------


    function createBidder(string memory _name ,string memory _pan , string memory _type , 
    string memory _city, string memory _state , uint _postalcode , string memory _companyCatagory ,
    string memory _nature)  public {

        bidders[bid].organisationId = bid ;
        bidders[bid].organisationName = _name;
        bidders[bid].add = msg.sender;
        bidders[bid].pan = _pan;
        bidders[bid].bidderType = _type;
        bidders[bid].city = _city ;
        bidders[bid].state = _state ;
        bidders[bid].postalCode = _postalcode;
        bidders[bid].companyCategory = _companyCatagory;
        bidders[bid].natureOfBusiness = _nature;
        bid++;
        bidderId[msg.sender] = bid ;
        isRegistered[msg.sender] = true;
    }


    //-------------------------- Add a bid ------------------------------------

    function addBid (uint _tid , uint _bidAmount ) public {

        if (winner[_tid].bidAmount == 0){
            winner[_tid].winner = msg.sender ;
            winner[_tid].bidAmount = _bidAmount;
            winner[_tid].tenderId = _tid;
        }
        else{
            if(winner[_tid].bidAmount > _bidAmount){
                winner[_tid].winner = msg.sender ;
                winner[_tid].bidAmount = _bidAmount;
                winner[_tid].tenderId = _tid;
            }
        }

        allBiddings[biddingCount].bidder = msg.sender;
        allBiddings[biddingCount].bidAmount = _bidAmount;
        allBiddings[biddingCount].tenderId = _tid;
        biddingCount++;
        isBidded[msg.sender][_tid] = true ;

    }

    //--------------------------- Close  a Tender ------------------------------------

    function closeTender(uint _tid) public {
        tenders[_tid].status = false ;
    }


    // ------------------------------verify bidder ---------------------------------
    function verifyBidder(address _bidder) public {
        isVerified[_bidder] = true ;
    }


    // ---------------------- isRegistered address ----------------------------------

    function isRegisteredBidder() view public returns(bool){
        return isRegistered[msg.sender];
    }

   // ----------------------isVerified address ---------------------------------

    function isVerifiedBidder() view public returns(bool){
        return isVerified[msg.sender];
    }


    //---------------------------- All Tender Details -----------------------------

    function allTenderDetails (uint _tid) view public returns (uint,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,uint , bool){
        return(
            tenders[_tid].tenderId,
            tenders[_tid].tenderName,
            tenders[_tid].tenderSector,
            tenders[_tid].tenderLocation,
            tenders[_tid].open,
            tenders[_tid].close,
            tenders[_tid].tenderCategory,
            tenders[_tid].prequalification,
            tenders[_tid].tenderValue,
            tenders[_tid].status);
    }

     function totalTenderLength() view public returns(uint){
        return tid;
    }


    //------------------------------ All bidder Details ----------------------------------

    function allBidderDetails(uint _bid) view public returns (uint,string memory,address ,string memory,string memory,string memory,
    string memory,uint,string memory,string memory,bool){
        return(
          bidders[_bid].organisationId,
          bidders[_bid].organisationName,
          bidders[_bid].add,
          bidders[_bid].pan,
          bidders[_bid].bidderType,
          bidders[_bid].city,
          bidders[_bid].state,
          bidders[_bid].postalCode,
          bidders[_bid].companyCategory,
          bidders[_bid].natureOfBusiness,
          isVerified[bidders[_bid].add] );
    }

    function totalBidderLength() view public returns(uint){
        return bid;
    }

    //-------------------------bidding detals ----------------------------------

    function allBiddingDetails(uint _i) view public returns (address , uint ,uint){
        return (allBiddings[_i].bidder,allBiddings[_i].bidAmount,allBiddings[_i].tenderId);
    }

    function totalBiddingLength() view public returns(uint){
        return biddingCount;
    }


    // --------------------------- Check is already bidded for this tender -----------

    function checkbiddedStatus(uint _tid) view public returns(bool){
        return isBidded[msg.sender][_tid];
    }

    // -------------------------Tender status ---------------------------------------

    function tenderStatus(uint _tid) view public returns(bool){
        return tenders[_tid].status;
    }


    //---------------------------address to BidderId ----------------------------
    function addToBid() view public returns(uint){
        return bidderId[msg.sender];
    }



} // ----------------------------------Contract End ---------------------------
```

it showing error as `InternalCompilerError: Stack too deep, try using fewer variables`

anyone, please help me to solve this smart contract error.

this is a tender creating a smart contract.

it contains

1. tender creation
2. bidder registration
3. bidding
4. other logics

also, I don't know how to set a function not to work after a particular date?

Comment: Probably one of your functions have too many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Both `allBidderDetails` and `allTenderDetails` exceed the amount of local variables a function can have in solidity.

You could encapsulate some of your variables in arrays or make public your mappings:

```
mapping(uint =>tender) public tenders;
mapping(uint =>tender) public bidders;
```

Then you could read them the same way you could magically use them like functions 
`yourContractInstance.methods.tenders(0);`

For more details take a look at this answer. 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7325/stack-too-deep-try-removing-local-variables